# What's the demanded behavior of vscode when there are multiple completionItems from multiple sources(extensions) with preselect = true

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, vscode-extensions

I am writing a VSCode auto-completion extension. I found that even I set preselect=true in my completionItem, the actual preselected completion item always comes from another completion extension I installed. VSCode seems NEVER to prefer completion items provided by my extension, even though the two extension returns identical result.

I checked the VSCode API doc, it says

> The rule is that the first item of those that match best is selected.

which is not clear at all：

What does the `first item` mean? Does it depend on the response time?

What does `match best` mean? to match what? context or prefix? and which measurement is used?

Is there anyone who knows how does VSCode choose the preselected item when there are multiple preselected result come from multiple sources?

Thanks a lot